# How to pass image data from one activity to another activity?

Tags: android

I am using two activities. One activity displays images in a `GridView` and by clicking on a particular image in that `GridView` it should display the full screen image in another activity.

How can I achieve this?

My MyGridView.java

```
mGridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position,long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Image"+(position+1),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    System.out.println(id);
    Intent i = new Intent(this, MyImageViewActivity.class);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putInt("image", position);
    i.putExtras(bundle);
    startActivityForResult(i, 0);
}
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MyGridView: (someInteger is an integer that represents the index of the selected image

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, MyImageViewActivity.class);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putInt("image", someInteger);
myIntent.putExtras(bundle);
startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
```

In MyImageViewActivity:

```
Bundle bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
int pic = bundle.getInt("image");
```

of course, you can put anything in the bundle! maybe a byte array or something

Comment: Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, yourOtherActivity.class);
shows error
"The constructor Intent(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){}, Class<MyImageViewActivity>) is undefined"

Comment: change yourOtherActivity to the class name of your second activity

Comment: Sorrry..i didn't get u!See,i have two class one is MyGridView.java and another is MyImageViewActivity.java. content i have written in MyGridView.java, is this correct way?

Comment: error solved but it shows error while running the project 
Error is "ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6367): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException"

Comment: then pic will be used by setimagresource??

Comment: yes, i changed with extra.putInt("image id", (int) id);
because it is 'long'
but not solved yet.

Comment: use putLong instead of putInt! and getLong instead of getInt

Comment: @Saurabh let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1313/discussion-between-sherif-and-saurabh)

Answer (score 3):

Pass the image URL/Uri instead of passing raw image data.

Comment: i have made array for the images.

Comment: It would be great if you could add a short pseudo code sample.

Answer (score 2):

You pass parameters to an Activity in an Intent.
If the image comes from a file, pass the path String, otherwise pass the Bitmap

```
startActivity(new Intent(this, YourActivity.class).putExtras(new Bundle().putParcelable("bitmap", Bitmap)))
```

Answer (score 2):

To pass the data between two activities:

```
bytes[] imgs = ... // your image
Intent intent = new Intent(this, YourActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("img", imgs);
startActivity(intent);
```

Then in YourActivity:

```
bytes[] receiver = getIntent().getExtra("imgs");
```

Also go thro this [link](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/11f252430b34f4b8/49cfea00e229d537?show_docid=49cfea00e229d537) which wil also help u.
Here u can know [how to convert bitmap to bytes](http://www.anddev.org/advanced-tutorials-f21/how-to-convert-bitmap-to-byte-array-in-android-t12985.html)

Answer (score 1):

Once an item of `Grid View` is clicked, get the clicked item and pass it to next `activity` as an argument through `PutExtra`. In the next activity retrieve the image from extras and display it to user

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you need use Intent class.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(YourSourceActivity.this, TargetActivty.class);
Bundle addinfo = new Bundle();

addinfo.putInt("imageid", someid);

intent.putExtras(addinfo);
```

Comment: Thanks man and plus In the target activity we just need                                                       Bundle bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
int pic = bundle.getInt("imageid");

Answer (score 0):

Try passing id related to image through intent.putExtra(), and receive it through bundle on launched activity.

Comment: all id which i m getting are 0. I don't know whether they are correct or not.

Answer (score 0):

in Activity convert the image to ByteArray and append it to the intent as

```
intent.putExtra("img",<ByteArray>);
```

then startActivity B.

In Activity B

```
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(getIntent().getByteArrayExtra("img"), 0, getIntent().getByteArrayExtra("img").length);
```

This way you can pass image between activity.

Answer (score 0):

This is my process: it's so good.
Activity1:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream stream=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100,stream);
    byte[] byteArray=stream.toByteArray();
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FrameActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("Image", byteArray);
    startActivity(intent);
```

in FrameActivity.class

```
collageView = (CollageView) findViewById(R.id.btn_collage);
    byte[] byteArray = getIntent().getByteArrayExtra("Image");
    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
    collageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```