# Passing data between activities android

Tags: android, android-activity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I pass data between activities in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-in-android)

I have been banging my head across the table for days trying to figure this out. I'm new to both Java and the Android platform and I am writing my second application. In a nutshell, I want the user to enter in some information in the first activity. That activity then takes those inputs and runs a series of mathematical computations and then displays the results in several editTexts in a separate activity. In my mind, the application takes the input, runs the computations and then stores them in some variables. The variables then need to be passed to the second activity which then displays the results. I have most of the application coded and I can get it to work properly if I keep the inputs and displayed results in one activity. Any Ideas on how I can get the displayed results to show up on another activity? Any direction here is much appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2091482/786914

Comment: more questions on this topic http://stackoverflow.com/q/6646979/964741

Answer (score 3):

This can be done with use of intent. one of the use of Intent is to pass the data between activities. In your scenario what you need to do is

### **STEP 1**

After taking input from the user, do computation, store result in
   the variables
bundle that in the intent which you are using to
    start next activity.    You can achieve this by below code

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.putExtra("KeyForResult1", <your variable>);
            intent.putExtra("KeyForResult2",<your variable>);
            startActivity(this, nextactivity.class);
```

in the nextactivity you need to get the intent and extract the values in the variable
   which can be achieved

```
variabletype variable = getIntent().getExtras().get("KeyForResult1");
   variabletype variable = getIntent().getExtras().get("KeyForResult2");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

**ActivityOne.class:**

```
//compute the data and get the result here
//suppose results are,

    int resultInt=24;
    String resultString="abc";

    Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ActivityTwo.class);
    intent.putExtra("ResultInInteger",resultInt);
    intent.putExtra("ResultInString",resultString);
    startActivity(intent);
```

this will open **ActivityTwo.class**,where you can get the data like:

```
int resultInt=getIntent().getIntExtra("ResultInInteger");
String resultString=getIntent().getStringExtra("ResultInString");
```

Comment: Maybe I am doing something wrong, but when I add the code in the second class, I keep getting an error on the "getIntExtra" snippet. I get "the method getIntExtra(String, int) in the type Intent is not applicable for the arguments (String)" any thoughts?

Comment: Yup...my mistake! you should provide default value in getting Integer Extra from an intent in 2nd activity.So use int resultInt=getIntent().getIntExtra("ResultInInteger",0); instead,in above answer.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to figure it out with a mixture of data I had researched. It seems what finally worked was

```
int resultInt=24;

Intent myIntent = new Intent(CalPalActivity.this, ResultsActivity.class);
myIntent.putExtra("intVariableName", resultInt);
startActivity(myIntent);
```

in the first activity and

```
Intent mIntent = getIntent();
int intValue = mIntent.getIntExtra("intVariableName", 0);
```

in the second. Why it worked like this and kept giving me errors such as "the method getIntExtra(String, int) in the type Intent is not applicable for the arguments (String)" in the second activity I'll never know. Even the Quick-fixes didn't fix it (I just kept getting new errors). All in all, it's an expensive (5 hour +) but well learned lesson. All of your help was much appreciated. I was able to understand and learn a great deal more about the language. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You should read up on [Intents](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html#iobjs). You can store extras in an intent, much like URL parameters. If you use that intent to start your next activity, it will be able to extract the data from the intent's extras.

Answer (score 0):

There are several options. For your task I'd choose passing the data in Intent's extras.

For all options read [this](http://developer.android.com/resources/faq/framework.html#3)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option.
In first Activity:

```
Intent yourNextActivityIn=new Intent(this,yourNextActivity.class);
yourNextActivityIn.putExtra("tag",valueToBePassed);
startActivity(yourNextActivityIn);
```

In second Activity:

```
//If value is an Integer with default value 1
int value = getIntent().getIntExtra("tag", 1);
```

else

```
//if value is a string
String value = getIntent().getStringExtra("tag");
```