# Transfer data from one screen to another on android eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, screen, switching

Hi am newbie to java and android.

Assume function `demo()` from the screenone is going to display some values on `Textview` which is on the same screen(screenone).

But i need to display that resultant value to the next screen ie.(screen two)

```
public void demo(){
{
 .....
 .....
}
```

---

So i have included these line to

**screenoneActivity.java**

```
Intent nextScreen = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SecondtwoActivity.class);
nextScreen.putExtra("","");
startActivity(nextScreen);
demo();
```

**ScreentwoActivity.java**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main1);

    TextView txtName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    Intent i = getIntent();

    txtName.setText(name);
```

I did these things so far.I don't know how to do transfer data from `demo()` function to the next screen.

Can anyone give me clues or  ideas to achieve this.

Thanks a lot!..

Comment: first search after then post question http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[android]+pass+data+in+activity

Comment: r u passing the data to activity 1 to activity2?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pass image data from one activity to another activity?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646979/how-to-pass-image-data-from-one-activity-to-another-activity)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to send some value into the putExtra methods parameters to be able to get something out of it.

In your first activity(A):

```
Intent i = new Intent(A.this, B.class);
i.putExtra("someName", variableThatYouNeedToPass);
startActivity(i);
```

In your second activity(B):

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
int fetchedVariable = extras.getInt("someName");
```

Answer (score 1):

Write the below code in demo() function:

```
Intent nextScreen = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SecondtwoActivity.class);
       nextScreen.putExtra("","");
       startActivity(nextScreen);
```

In `nextScreen.putExtra("","");` provide some key and value like:

```
nextScreen.putExtra("name","ABC");
```

Now in SecondActivity, write:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main1);

    TextView txtName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    Intent i = getIntent();
    Bundle bundle = i.getExtras();

    txtName.setText(bundle.getString("name"));
```

Answer (score 1):

In ScreenoneActivity

```
Intent act2=new Intent(this,Activity2.class);
    act2.putExtra("A",a);
    startActivity(act2);
```

In ScreentwoActivity class

```
Intent i = getIntent();
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 
int a = extras.getInt("A");
txtName.setText(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

in onCreate :

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 
String value;

if (extras != null) 
{
    value= extras.getString("key");
}
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10752501/how-can-we-go-to-next-page-in-android/10752516#10752516

google it is very basic .....

android using intent....

[Vogella Ariticle](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidIntent/article.html)

in activity 1-

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, ActivityTwo.class);
i.putExtra("Value1", "This value one for ActivityTwo ");
i.putExtra("Value2", "This value two ActivityTwo");

startActivity(i);
```

In activity 2 - in onCreate finction

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

if (extras == null) {
        return;
        }
// Get data via the key
String value1 = extras.getString(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
if (value1 != null) {
    // Do something with the data
}
```